# No @Field type in spring-data-couchbase2.1.1Release

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I was using spring-data-couchbase1.4.0Release it was having @Field annotation to inform the compiler that it is part of the json. But in Spring-data-couchbase2.0 and above none of the version has @field annotation.

What is the substitute for it?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Field` annotation has been moved in the SDK artifact. That said, you don't strictly need it if you only want to specify which attributes to include in the JSON:

- there is a Spring Data Common `@Transient` annotation that will exclude a property from being considered by Spring Data
- by default all properties are included
- `@Field` can be used to customize the name under which the property is stored in Couchbase though...